Create an IF statement based on the rebate terms given (which differs for every supplier) [IF X is between 0-50k then 10% but if X 51k-100k then 12%]
In excel I have a table of 4 columns: Supplier, Turnover YTD, Rebate Terms, Rebate %. In the rebate terms column this shows the % we return depending on the turnover amount and this differs for each supplier. For example supplier XYZ has rebates term 0-9,999 = 0, 10,000-24,999 = 2%, 25,000+ then 3%.
This would be easy if the rebate terms were the same for every supplier but each supplier changes so I think I need to try a search then an IF, do you know if this is possible.
See an example of some data:



Supplier
Turnover YTD
Rebate Terms
Rebate %




XYZ PLC
£700.00
"£0 to £9,999 = £0  £10,000 to £24,999 = 2%  £25,000+ = 3% of total spend"
x


ABC PLC
£30,000.00
"£25K to £50K = 1.5%  £50K to £200K = 2.5%  £200K+ = 5.0% of total spend"
x


JJ PLC
£1,000,000.00
"£0 to £1,099,999 = 1.0%  £1,100,000 to £1,299,999 = 2.0%  £1,300,000+ = 4.0%"
x


LL PLC
£700.00
"£0 to £299,999 = 3.0%  £300,000 to £399,999 = 3.5%  £400,000 to £449,999 = 4.0%  £450,000+ = x
x



Thanks,
Currently I've just got an IF function based on each rebate but this is extremely long winded.
for example:
=IF(B3<10000, B3*0,
IF(AND(B3>=10000, B3<25000), B3*0.02,
IF(B3>=25000, B3*0.03,"ERROR")))

Wondering if there is a search I can do beforehand?

Normalize the data first.  Then it can be done.  But parsing a string in a cell to get the spans and percentages is probably too much for a formula.

Also, it would help if you posted the data as a markdown table and not an image so we can copy paste your data and not need to retype what you already have typed.

Thanks Scott, I've added a markdown table now!

Can I also ask how you would go about normalising the data?

Have a separate table with one column that has the Supplier and then a column for the minimum level and a third for the rebate.  Then it would be a simple XLOOKUP of the FILTERED data.

Another thing.  Those 20K etc will make this really difficult. They should be full numbers.

To do it with what you have we have to use formula to normalize the data to do a VLOOKUP:
=VLOOKUP(B2,DROP(REDUCE("",TEXTSPLIT(C2,CHAR(10)),LAMBDA(_z,_y,VSTACK(_z,HSTACK(TAKE(TOROW(--TEXTSPLIT(_y,{" ","+","="}),3),,1),TAKE(TOROW(--TEXTSPLIT(_y,{" ","+","="}),3),,-1))))),1),2,TRUE)

The whole DROP() part is to normalize the cell.
NOTE: I had to change the K to their numerical values to make this work.  The values need to be actual numbers and not a string. Also this assumes that £9,999 will convert to a number that the monetary notation is local for your settings, I had to change to $ to make work


Now if you normalize the data:

Then the formula is much simpler:
=VLOOKUP(B2,FILTER(O:P,N:N=A2),2,TRUE)


